# Laravel Loop through nested array

Tags: json, laravel, cart

```
{
  "8": {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Third Product",
    "price": 3000,
    "quantity": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "tax": 7.5,
      "shop": "Edificeweb",
      "image": "rp-4.jpg"
    },
    "conditions": []
  },
  "9": {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "The fourth",
    "price": 200,
    "quantity": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "tax": 7.5,
      "shop": "Edificeweb",
      "image": "product-2.jpg"
    },
    "conditions": []
  }
}
```

I stored my cart as a json column in my order page... How do I check for authenticated user using `whereJsonContains`....

I tried

```
$Order=Order::whereJsonContains('cart->attributes->shop',Auth::user()->name)->get();
```

It returns empty array

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with mysql you should try something like:

```
$Order = Order::whereJsonContains('cart->attributes', ['shop' => Auth::user()->name])->first();
```

With postgresql try with:

```
$Order = Order::whereJsonContains('cart->attributes', [['shop' => Auth::user()->name]])->first();
```

If it's case sensitivity you should try raw:

```
$Order = Order::whereJsonContains(DB::raw('lower("cart->attributes"::text)'),
    [["shop" => strtolower(Auth::user()->name)]])->first();
```

I recommend that you save the objects without numbers as indicators, if you are saving it with numbers as indicators ("9", "8") you should try:

```
$Order = Order::whereJsonContains('cart->"$[*].attributes"', ['shop' => Auth::user()->name])->first();
```

**btw, I would recommend that you use first instead of get but it would be better for you to try it and see what your convenience is ;)**

Comment: Its returns null when I used first() and empty arrary when I use get()

Comment: do i need to do protected $casts=[ 'cart '= 'array ']; in my order model to perform whereJsonContans??

Comment: @BobsonEdidiong you can cast it but that it's not necessary to use the function, I think your problem is that you cannot access the attributes due to the numerical indicators